# How to display weekdays in DayPilot Event calendar

Tags: daypilot

Does anybody know how to display week-days (monday, tuesday, ...) in DayPilot event calendar? I can only show date.
http://www.daypilot.org/calendar-lite/ http://code.daypilot.org/17910/html5-event-calendar-open-source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use headerDateFormat to set the date format used in the column headers.

The "dddd" format string will display the day of week:

```
<div id="dp"></div>

<script>

  var dp = new DayPilot.Calendar("dp");
  // ...
  dp.headerDateFormat = "dddd"; // day of week, long format (e.g. "Monday")
  dp.init();

</script>
```

See also the [Header Date Format](http://doc.daypilot.org/calendar/header-date-format/) topic in the docs.

Comment: Thanks. I belive it is the correct answer. In my case it doesn't help me because some of the functionalities in the documentation doesn't work in my code, just some works.